# Tests, using Aruba with Rspec, failing with `run` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block)

Tags: ruby, rspec, console-application, aruba

I need to test a console application and check printed output, using rspec script. Example:

```
RSpec.describe 'Test Suite', type: :aruba do

  it "has aruba set up" do
    command = run("echo 'hello world'")
    stop_all_commands
    expect(command.output).to eq("hello world\n")
  end
```

It fails with:

```
Failure/Error: command = run("echo 'hello world'")
   `run` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

Aruba version 0.14.6, Rspec 3.7.0. Will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Where run method is defined?

Comment: According documentation (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/aruba/Aruba/Api/Commands#run_command-instance_method) it should be run_command, but it fails with Unknown command. Looks like `run` is the correct for this version of Aruba::Api. Documentation is w.......

Comment: "Where run method is defined?" - God knows..... found nothing on the net. :(

Answer (score 0):

As the error implies, you cannot call `run` within the `it` block. Aruba's documentation can get a bit confusing here because of the various branches, but the `run` method is still available in the `still` branch, with documentation found [here](https://app.cucumber.pro/projects/aruba/documents/branch/still/features/api/command/run.feature).

Following the documentation, instead of defining `command`  within the `it` block, we can instead define it outside the block using `let`:

```
RSpec.describe 'Test Suite', type: :aruba do
  context "aruba test" do
    let(:command) { run("echo 'hello world'") }
    it "has aruba set up" do
      stop_all_commands
      expect(command.output).to eq("hello world\n")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Failure/Error: stop_all_commands
     
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `stop_all_commands' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::....